# Dropdown menu floating left

Tags: html, css

I made a menu, and I want the dropdown to go centered underneath the 'Fruitsoorten' tab. But now all three of the items are next to each other.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-right: 15%;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 55px;
  background-color: black;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav li ul {
  display: none;
}
nav li li {
  display:
}
nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="geschiedenis.html">Fruitsoorten</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="team.html">Kersen</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html">Appels</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html">Pruimen</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li>
    <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>
    <li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a></li>
    <li><a href="vacatures.html">Vacatures</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Adding a fiddle would be nice!

Comment: There's an empty `display` property for the `nav li li` selector in the middle, Try setting it to `block` for example and continue investigating from there.

Comment: @Rohit416 Ok, https://jsfiddle.net/wygwke83/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this styles. 
http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/LkyQvq

```
nav {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 55px;
  background-color: black;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  display:block;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to reflect

```
nav ul { margin-top: 0; } 
nav li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Also clear your HTML code with proper closing of `</li>`

Answer (score 0):

To affect your `inline-block` styling to main `ul` only, 
Do this:

```
nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

instead of

```
nav li { display: inline-block; position: relative; padding: 10px; }
```

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-right: 15%;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 55px;
  background-color: black;
}
nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav li ul {
  display: none;
}
nav li li {
  display:
}
nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="geschiedenis.html">Fruitsoorten</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="team.html">Kersen</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="team.html">Appels</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="team.html">Pruimen</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="team.html">Team</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="vacatures.html">Vacatures</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

*is that what you want?*

```css
nav {
float: right;
border-radius: 15px;
margin-right: 15%;
}

nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
background-color: black;
}

nav li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding: 10px;
}

nav li ul {
display: none;
}

nav li li {
display: 
}

nav li:hover ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
padding:0;
}

nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
}

nav li:hover {
background-color: gray;
}
ul.inner li{width:83%}
```

```html
    <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="geschiedenis.html">Fruitsoorten</a>
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li><a href="team.html">Kersen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="team.html">Appels</a></li>
                    <li><a href="team.html">Pruimen</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li>
                <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a>
                <li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a></li>
                <li><a href="vacatures.html">Vacatures</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```